# Elementor icons control icon not showing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

My elementor icons control icon not showing. When I drag and drop my widget into elementor edit section for the first time then it's not (Icon not showing) working but when I change my icon then it showing fine. What's the problem? And how can I solve the problem?

```
<?php
  namespace MeetTheTeam\Widgets;

  use Elementor\Widget_Base;
  use Elementor\Controls_Manager;

  if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

  class MTTTest extends Widget_Base {
    public function get_name() {
      return 'team-mtt-widgetdd';
    }
    public function get_title() {
      return __( 'Team Sectionsdd', 'meet_the_team' );
    }
    public function get_icon() {
      return 'eicon-image-rollover';
    }
    public function get_categories() {
      return [ 'meet-the-team' ];
    }
    public function get_script_depends() {
      return [ 'meet_the_teamd' ];
    }
    
    protected function _register_controls() {
      $this->start_controls_section(
        'section_icond',
        [
          'label' => __( 'Icon', 'text-domain' ),
        ]
      );
      
      $repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();
      
      $repeater->add_control(
        'mtt_social_icon_three_sk',
        [
          'label' => esc_html__( 'Icon', 'meet_the_team' ),
          'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::ICONS,
          'default' => [
            'value' => 'fab fa-linkedin',
            'library' => 'solid',
          ],
        ]
      );

      $this->add_control(
        'mtt_boxfgfg',
        [
          'label' => esc_html__( 'Meet The Team', 'meet_the_team' ),
          'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
          'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
          'default' => [
            [
              'mtt_box_title' => esc_html__( 'Title #1', 'meet_the_team' ),
            ],
            [
              'mtt_box_title' => esc_html__( 'Title #2', 'meet_the_team' ),
            ],
          ],
          'title_field' => `{{{ mtt_box_title }}}`,
        ]
      );

      $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    protected function render() {
      $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
      if ( $settings['mtt_boxfgfg'] ) {
        foreach (  $settings['mtt_boxfgfg'] as $item ) {
        ?>
        <div class="test_icon"><i class="<?php echo esc_html($item['mtt_social_icon_three_sk']['value']); ?>"></i></div>
        <?php
      }
    }
  }

    protected function _content_template() {
      ?>
      <# if ( settings.mtt_boxfgfg.length ) { #>
        <# _.each( settings.mtt_boxfgfg, function( item ) { #>
          <div class="test_icon"><i class="{{{item['mtt_social_icon_three_sk']['value']}}}"></i></div>
        <# }); #>
      <# } #>
    <?php
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the font awesome script loaded with fab fa-linkedin, try with fa fa-linkedin

Comment: fa fa-linkedin also not working

Comment: Try Inspect element with firefox in page, and view what class you have on that icon you expect to be there <i class="">

Comment: first time class are not showing but when i edit the icon then the class are showing

Comment: in your code have 2 icons, 1 escaped 1 not, do both escaped ```<i class="<?php echo esc_html($item['mtt_social_icon_three_sk']['value']); ?>"></i>``` instead of ```<i class="{{{item['mtt_social_icon_three_sk']['value']}}}"></i>```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.